# Saving Calendar entries when deleting exchange account

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, calendar, exchange, macos

Recently left a job and am deleting the Exchange account from my MacBook Air associated with the company. I no longer have access to the account (password has been changed, naturally) but I would really like to keep my calendar entries, mainly because I wasn't religious about where I placed appointments and I'd like to be able to look back and see what I did when at some point.

So, is there a way to either delete the Exchange account without deleting existing entries in Calendar (un-sync it or something?) or quickly copy all entries from one account into another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am basing this on something I have done in earlier versions of Calendar, like when it was called "iCal" so YMMV.

You should be able to select the specific calendar in calendar.app and then export it to an .ical file. Then delete your exchange account (did it sync Address Books as well?) and then if it just deleted the calendar you can re-import it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save your calendar entries in the following way, [as reported here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204055):

1. Go to [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/), sign in with your Apple ID, and open Calendar.
2. Publicly share the calendar.
3. Copy the URL of the shared calendar and paste it into the address field in your browser. Don't press Enter or Return.
4. Change "webcal" to "http" and press Enter or Return. An ICS file will download to your default download location.
5. Add the calendar to a calendar client, such as Calendar on Mac or Outlook on a Windows computer or Calendar by Google.
6. Stop sharing the calendar.